# My magento theme is not able to load CSS

Tags: html, css, xml, magento

I am building a magento website. I have uploaded all blocks and skin and app folders. But, although I have change Design parametres, my theme hasn`t CSS style. My web is:
www.droidotech.com
How I could add CSS?

Comment: Do they show in your theme's local.xml (app\design\frontend\theme\layout\local.xml)?

Comment: No, I don`t have that file

Comment: accept the answer if you find helpful @Sergiohernandez

Comment: None has solved the problem, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `styles.css` calling from base means http://droidotech.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css

I think you dosen't set your `Skin (Images / CSS)` theme name from `system>config>design` or i think there is problem with `Base Skin URL` `system>config>web`.

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I use "skin/frontend/default/my_theme/css" , but I found theme-blue.css, theme-green.css instead of style.css , Where could I find it? Base Skin URL have {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

Answer (score 0):

There should be default CSS declared in `page.xml`, which is located in in your theme's layout folder.  You can add your own CSS by creating `local.xml` (which is the file you should use to modify any layout XML, so your changes don't ever get over-written by updates) with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>    
            <reference name="head">         
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```